# Конфигурация php.ini

Tags: php, php-fpm

Я скомпилировал `php`, есть только один файл `php.ini` в директории `/etc/php7.2/config`, как сделать так, чтобы при загрузке `php-fpm` загружался свой файл `php.ini`, а при загрузке `php-cli` свой файл `php.ini`? спасибо

Компилировал `php` с параметрами `--enable-fpm --prefix=/usr/local/php7.2 --with-config-file-path=/etc/php7.2/config`

Comment: дак скопируйте и переименуйте в `php-cli.ini`

Answer (score 0):

Из мануала на php.net - [файл конфигурации](http://php.net/manual/ru/configuration.file.php):

> Если файл php-SAPI.ini существует (где SAPI - это тип интерфейса, который используется, например, php-cli.ini или php-apache.ini), то он используется вместо php.ini. Тип интерфейса между веб-сервером и PHP может быть определен с помощью функции php_sapi_name().

Вам достаточно создать файл php-cli.ini. Если же используется не cli, узнать текущее название интерфейса можно вызвав функцию `php_sapi_name()`